# SIMD: implement _mm256_max_epu64_ and _mm256_min_epu64_

Tags: c++, simd, avx2, avx512

I want to ask a question about SIMD.
I don't get the `AVX512` in my CPU but want to have a [_mm256_max_epu64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_max_epu64&expand=730,4929,3837,624,776,3705,776,3705,1011,931,3705,3616,3582,3591).

How can we implement this function with `AVX2`?

Here I try to have my trivial one. Maybe we can let it be a discussion and improve that.

```
#define SIMD_INLINE inline __attribute__ ((always_inline)) 

SIMD_INLINE __m256i __my_mm256_max_epu64_(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
  uint64_t *val_a = (uint64_t*) &a;
  uint64_t *val_b = (uint64_t*) &b;
  uint64_t e[4];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) e[i] = (*(val_a + i) > *(val_b + i)) ? *(val_a + i) : *(val_b + i);
  return _mm256_set_epi64x(e[3], e[2], e[1], e[0]);
}
```

---

**EDIT** as a Summary:

We had a discussion about the `__mm256` **unsigned comparing**. I gave my trivial implementation above just following the very basic concept: a single `__m256i` is just equivalent with 4 `uint64_t` or 4 `float`, which also make up 256 bits together.

Then we had the answer from @chtz, which makes more `AVX` sense with calling more bit programming functions from `AVX`.

At end it turns out these two implementation result in the same assembly thanks to `CLang`. [Assembly example from compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/afhdOa)

---

Another `_mm256_min_epu64_` added. It is just mirroring the `_mm256_max_epu64_` above. Make it easier to be searched for the future use.

```
SIMD_INLINE __m256i __my_mm256_min_epu64_(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
  uint64_t *val_a = (uint64_t*) &a;
  uint64_t *val_b = (uint64_t*) &b;
  uint64_t e[4];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) e[i] = (*(val_a + i) < *(val_b + i)) ? *(val_a + i) : *(val_b + i);
  return _mm256_set_epi64x(e[3], e[2], e[1], e[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be a combination of `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64` with a blend.
However, if you want the unsigned maximum, you need to first subtract `1<<63` from each element (before comparison, not before blending).
There is no `_mm256_blendv_epu64` instruction, but it is possible to use `_mm256_blendv_epi8` since the mask will set at every bit of the relevant elements. Also note that subtracting the uppermost bit can be done by a slightly faster `xor`:

```
__m256i pmax_epu64(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    __m256i signbit = _mm256_set1_epi64x(0x8000'0000'0000'0000);
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cmpgt_epi64(_mm256_xor_si256(a,signbit),_mm256_xor_si256(b,signbit));
    return _mm256_blendv_epi8(b,a,mask);
}
```

Actually, clang almost manages to get the same instructions from your code: https://godbolt.org/z/afhdOa
It only uses `vblendvpd` instead of `vpblendvb`, which may introduce latencies (see @PeterCordes comment for details).

With some bit-twiddeling you could actually save setting the register for the signbit. 
An unsigned comparison gives the same result if the signs of both operands match and the opposite results if they don't match, i.e.

```
unsigned_greater_than(signed a, signed b) == (a<0) ^ (b<0) ^ (a>b)
```

This can be used if you use the `_mm256_blendv_pd` with some casting as a `_mm256_blendv_epi64` (because now only the uppermost bit is valid):

```
__m256i _mm256_blendv_epi64(__m256i a, __m256i b, __m256i mask)
{
    return _mm256_castpd_si256(_mm256_blendv_pd(
        _mm256_castsi256_pd(a),_mm256_castsi256_pd(b),_mm256_castsi256_pd(mask)));
}

__m256i pmax_epu64_b(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    __m256i opposite_sign = _mm256_xor_si256(a,b);
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cmpgt_epi64(a,b);
    return _mm256_blendv_epi64(b,a,_mm256_xor_si256(mask, opposite_sign));
}
```

Just for reference, a signed maximum is of course just:

```
__m256i pmax_epi64(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cmpgt_epi64(a,b);
    return _mm256_blendv_epi8(b,a,mask);
}
```

Comment: Using the result of `vblendvpd` as an input to integer instructions may cause an extra 1 cycle of latency for those integer instructions, so be careful if you're using the result repeatedly.  (On Haswell/Skylake, the origin of a register value seems to "stick", increasing latency for the *other* input even if the domain-crossing input has been ready for a long time, and is used repeatedly.)

Comment: You should probably just **use `vpblendvb` (`_mm256_blendv_epi8`) like normal for integer variable-blends**, because `cmpgt_epi64` sets all bits of the whole element.  If you were doing something that only set the high bit of a 64-bit element, then it might be worth using a `pd` FP blend.  `vpblendvb` and `vblendvpd` cost the same on Intel and AMD CPUs with AVX2, and we know AVX2 is available because we're using `vpcmpgtq`.  This appears to be a clang missed-optimization.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added a `pmax_epu64` variant which relies on using the uppermost bit. But that is likely only useful in a few cases.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the simple/good integer-blend version first, and move the definition of the `_pd` wrapper later, along with the XOR hack that avoids the vector constant.  The answer you present to future readers shouldn't be a mis-step and then the correction.  This is why editing isn't restricted to append-only.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I rewrote the answer. Also put the signed max to the very end, since that was not what the OP asked for. Hope I did not miss anything important now.